# how to extract value from multiple soap response in jmeter xpath extractor

Tags: xpath, soap, jmeter

I have two soap responses and want to extract Id based on taskLabel. What I have done so far is used xpath query:

```
//orderHeader/[@taskLabel='PROVIDE_QUOTE_OR_REJECT_RFQ']/@taskId
```

but its not extracting the taskId.

I was unable extract task Id against `<taskLabel>TEST_LABEL1</taskLabel>` in below soap response:

```
<orderHeader>
    <taskId>56657</taskId>
    <taskName>Test Label</taskName>
    <taskLabel>TEST_LABEL</taskLabel>
</orderHeader>

<orderHeader>
    <taskId>56656</taskId>
    <taskName>Test Label</taskName>
    <taskLabel>TEST_LABEL1</taskLabel>
</orderHeader>
```

When I tried this XPath Query: `//orderHeader/taskId` 
It only extracts the task Id from 1st soap response.

PS: The task Id I want to extract is not fixed to be in the 2nd response it can be in any response.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

//orderHeader[taskName/text()='TEST_LABEL1']/taskId/text()

Answer (score 1):

Use `@` to reference element attribute. In your case, `taskLabel` and `taskId` are elements instead, so the correct XPath would be :

```
//orderHeader[taskLabel='PROVIDE_QUOTE_OR_REJECT_RFQ']/taskId
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be using something like:

```
//taskLabel[text()='TEST_LABEL1']/../taskId/text()
```

Demo:

[image: XPath Extractor]

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Language Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)